# How to set a personal title for your web browser tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-tab

In my web browser (chrome or firefox), I have a few tabs of the same website or the same page (because of testing purposes). I would like to know what tab is for when reading my tab titles.

> For instance, I have 3 tabs of the same page (so the same title is displayed in web browser) and I would like to set a title different for each to know what is the purpose of each tab. But this name is only for me (and I need it to be kept because I often refresh my tabs ; so no JS).

Do you know if there is a solution in Chrome or Firefox to set a "nickname" for the tabs? I would like to rename a tab in `DONT REFRESH DAT` to remember this tab musn't be refreshed. It's like a post-it for my tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that seems to be good in Chrome and Firefox plugins. It's called `Rename Tab Title` and here are the links:

- [Chrome - Rename Tab Title](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rename-tab-title/kppndhfiaenbiioipolacicknfmdcdep?hl=en-GB)
- [Firefox - Rename Tab Title](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rename-tab-title/)

If the tab is refreshed, the name is kept (it works with Chrome auto-refresh).

If a JS script rename the tab, the name set by the plugin will be erased.